# Neither atom or visual code shows dataset output

Tags: python, pandas, csv, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I have downloaded a Kaggle Netflix csv ([here](https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/netflix-shows#netflix_titles_nov_2019.csv)). Then I tried to open it using the following code on both atom and visual studio:

```
import pandas as pd
datapath='~/Downloads/netflix_titles_nov_2019.csv'
netflixdata=pd.read_csv(datapath)
netflixdata.describe()
```

It runs without error but does not output anything. However, when I do it on the terminal it shows the .csv information. 
Am I missing something? Like an extension, etc..

Comment: Did you try any other function suchh as `.head()`?

Comment: Surround it with `print`.

Comment: How are you running your script?

Comment: Hey guys, its solved..I just forgot the print function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When running commands in terminal, things operate differently. If you are running your code in an IDE of sorts, you need to tell your code to display the output. If you just want to visually see it, this can be done as easy as just `print`ing the output with `print(netflixdata.describe())`

Comment: Oh sure, my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

If you are expecting output from a script, you should surround it with `print`.

### Explanation

In Python, the way an object is displayed is governed by its `__repr__` function (think "representation"). Here's an example:

```py
class MyUncoolClass:
    pass

class MyCoolClass:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Check out this repr"

>>> MyUncoolClass()
<__main__.MyUncoolClass object at 0x1063c0048>
>>> MyCoolClass()
Check out this repr
```

When you call `netflixdata.describe()`, you get a data frame back:

```py
>>> type(netflixdata.describe())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

What you are actually viewing when you call `.describe()` in the shell is the output of the dataframe's `__repr__` function, which is a string. This string will be shown when you print it, or when it's displayed in the console. However, when you run a python script, unless you (or something else) explicitly calls `print` on some object, it will not be printed.

Comment: Sure, I just confused myself a bit. Thanks